Why pseudo-elements can't be used as an argument within :has() pseudo-class?
The CSS specs give following reason why pseudo-elements can't be used as an argument within :has() pseudo-class:

Note: Pseudo-elements are generally excluded from :has() because many
of them exist conditionally, based on the styling of their ancestors,
so allowing these to be queried by :has() would introduce cycles or
cyclic querying.

What's an example of this with pseudo-elements allowed as an argument within the :has() pseudo-class based on the above reason?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You would essentially be creating an infinite loop.
If .greeting:has(p::before) then give p a ::before, which would make .greeting:has(p::before) true, which influences itself and so on...


.greeting:has(p::before) p::before {
  content: "test";
  color: hotpink;
}
<div class="greeting">
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>



